# The interaction between hadoop hdfs block size and linux file system block size

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I understood hadoop block size is 64MB and linux FS is 4KB.
My understanding from reading is that hadoop hdfs work on top of linux FS itself.

How does hadoop file system actually work with linux 4KB block size?
Does 64MB block get broken down to 4KB blocks and saved to the disk during write operation, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, what you said is correct. HDFS is just an abstraction above Linux FS  where a block of 64MB is stored in continuous blocks of 4KB linux FS to have fast access. When you write 64MB of HDFS block will be treated as a single file by Linux and internally it breaks it down to 4KB blocks.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  If somebody tries to design a new SSD-type storage hardware than can "bypass" 4KB Linux block size limitation to MB-size blocks or even 64MB. Perhaps using a custom kernel and hardware, will that actually advantageous to get better performance for hadoop?

Comment: Yes, but not as much as you'd expect. That's because HDFS is specifically designed to take advantage of the read / write properties of conventional hard disks. An SSD is going to be way faster for seeking data, but since HDFS is storing its data in sequential series of blocks, the overall performance of a conventional hard drive is surprisingly good.

Comment: How to mark as answered?  
I found this hugepages feature on redhat. I wonder if this feature actually bypass the 4K block?
https://rhsummit.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/shak-larry-gray-summit-perf-analysis-and-tuning-part-1-20131.pdf

Comment: According to my opinion 4KB blocks are optimally designed to handle small and large files. If you have a large block size as big as 64MB you might want 64MB to store a 1byte file.     You can mark answers  by clickin g on tick mark left to answer.